# SFTP a file created on SQL Server with a Stored Procedure to a UNIX Server

Tags: unix, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms, sftp

I'm trying to create a SQL Server Stored Procedure to generate an XML file. Once the file is generated, it has to SFTP the file to a UNIX Server. I've never done the SFTP stuff before so here I'm seeking help. Please take a look at the below Stored Procedure that I've written and help me out.

```
USE [myDB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROC [dbo].[GenerateXML]
AS
SELECT FileID, SystemID, FileName
FROM dbo.File
FOR XML raw('File'), elements, root('File')
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(255)
SET @cmd = 'osql -E /Q  “exec GenerateXMLproc”  /o usadevenv01:/home/xml/file.xml'
EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd
GO
```

Comment: If you just want to send the file, then `scp` often is the better choice compared to `scp`. It uses the same server and protocol (`ssh`), but is non-interactive.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain how do I use SCP in a Stored Procedure

Answer (score 2):

i was facing a similar problem and i solved it using SSIS and a free tool called WINSCP.

First you shuold know that:

> By default, SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) do not support
>   access to SFTP sites. One way of getting it done is by using third
>   party software, There's a free tool called WinSCP which provides a
>   command line utility to communicate with SFTP sites. It has to be
>   scripted from the command line and then executed from SSIS.

then...

> The first step is to download and install WinSCP, you will need to do
>   this on the SQL server that will be running the SSIS package.  Once
>   you have installed WinSCP you should create a connection to the
>   distant sFTP server in WinSCP so you can test and confirm that you can
>   connect to it.  Create and name a saved session so that you can call
>   that session from your script later.

finally...

> Deploy and Execute SSIS Packages using Stored Procedures

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23740/SFTP-with-SSIS-Packages

http://gregcaporale.wordpress.com/2012/02/23/using-sftp-in-sql-server-ssis/

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj820152.aspx

good luck!